# Call Derived Method only if Base Method Completes

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, overriding, dry

I feel like this is a common scenario, and I'm curious if there's a best practice solution.

Like all of WPF, I have a method on my `ViewModelBase` that sets a property value and calls `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(string propertyName, ref T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    if (Equals(oldValue, newValue)) return;

    oldValue = newValue;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

I have a derived class `SaveableViewModelBase` that does some error checking and other things, that overrides `SetProperty`:

```
protected override void SetProperty<T>(string propertyName, ref T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    base.SetProperty(propertyName, ref oldValue, newValue);
    ValidateProperty(propertyName, newValue);
}
```

My issue is, if `Base` returns prematurely because the items are equal, I don't want to call my `Derived` code.  Of course I know of a few ways to do this:

1. `SetProperty` can return a bool that `Derived` checks (seems ugly as the other 1000 users of this method don't care about the return value)
2. Re-check whether the two properties are equal in `Derived` (simple, but not DRY)

I always like to stay DRY, I was just curious if there's a common solution to this problem that is considered a best-practice?  It seems like it'd be a pretty common scenario across the entire framework.

Comment: Do you want the base.SetProperty to run if your validation fails? It seems like your ValidateProperty should run first and only set the base property if the values validate.  ValidateProperty would either return a bool or throw an exception on failure.

Comment: base.SetProperty doesn't care about validation.  `ValidateProperty` does things like add to an `Errors` collection and disable the save button.

Comment: Just return a bool from SetProperty. If others don't want to use it they don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Look's like paranoia, but if it so important, maybe you shall try to not to use inheritance in that case and create Base class with Validation (and, maybe, also abstract superclass for both ViewModelBases)

Comment: it's definitely paranoia

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delegate method to onpropertychange in new derived class and when onpropertychange is triggered, it will run ValidateProperty method  in this newly method invoked to event. So you can remove Validateproperty method in derived method, and you will no need new override method because you can trigger Validateproperty on property change.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a second function to specify what needs to happen upon changing a property. Define a virtual method in the base that doesn't do anything, call that method inside `SetProperty`, then override the virtual method in the subclass.

In the base class you would do this:

```
protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(string propertyName, ref T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    if (Equals(oldValue, newValue)) return;

    oldValue = newValue;
    // Validate the property that was just changed.
    PropertyValidate(propertyName, ref oldValue, newValue);
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}

protected virtual void PropertyValidate<T>(string propertyName, ref T oldValue, T newValue)
{}
```

And in the subclass:

```
protected override void PropertyValidate<T>(string propertyName, ref T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    // Do some validation, adding some red marks to bad things.
}
```

---

Another solution (the overcomplicated one I thought of first) is callbacks. You could give `SetProperty<T>` an `Action` parameter and have the overriding `SetProperty<T>` add validation into the `Action`. Something like:

```
protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(
    string propertyName,
    ref T oldValue,
    T newValue,
    Action onChanged = null)
{
    if (Equals(oldValue, newValue)) return;

    oldValue = newValue;
    onChanged?.Invoke(); // Invoke the onChanged action (if not null).
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}

protected override void SetProperty<T>(
    string propertyName,
    ref T oldValue,
    T newValue,
    Action onChanged = null)
{
    // Wrap the given onChanged callback with a new one that also validates the property.
    base.SetProperty(propertyName, ref oldValue, newValue,
        () => { onChanged?.Invoke(); ValidateProperty(propertyName, newValue); });
}
```